# Python sockets: How can I tell the server that my client will not send more data?

Tags: python, sockets, client

I am trying to communicate with a server programmed in C. I am writing a client using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. The server is blocking on the following line:

```
read(fd, input_buffer, 0xffff);
```

Now, with my Python client, I send some data:

```
socket.sendto("Hello", (host, port))
```

However, the server continues to block on the call to `read()` - I believe it's expecting more data. I have confirmed that I can communicate with the server in general, but this one call continues to block. How can I tell the server that I will not send any further data, so that it may unblock?

Comment: You have to close socket.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your advice. I tried calling `socket.close()` after sending the data, but the server still hangs at the `read()` call.

Comment: Normaly closed socket/connection gives signal `EOF` (`End Of File`) and it is information about end of data. You could try command `telnet` in console/cmd.exe to connect to server and see what happends with server when you close `telnet`.

Comment: Did you wrote the C server ? Are you sure host and port are the good ones ? Is there a firewall blocking your packets ? What makes you think that the server blocks ? strace ? (strace is my friend) What does sendto returns ?

Comment: Any chance the server is waiting for data on a TCP connection and you send a UDP packet which the server will never see?  Because normally you would `connect()` to the server and send the data with `send()` or `sendall()`, possibly followed by closing the connection, depending on the protocol and what the server expects.